# Find unique number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to write a SQL query to find the number of unique working days for each employee from table `times`.

```
*---------------------------------------*
|emp_id  task_id  start_day   end_day   |
*---------------------------------------*
|  1        1     'monday'  'wednesday' |
|  1        2     'monday'  'tuesday'   |
|  1        3     'friday'  'friday'    |
|  2        1     'monday'  'friday'    |
|  2        1     'tuesday' 'wednesday' |
*---------------------------------------*
```

Expected output:

```
*-------------------*
|emp_id  no_of_days |
*-------------------*
|  1        4       |
|  2        5       |
*-------------------*
```

I have written the query [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/54b5d/11) which is giving me the `expected` output but for *curiosity* is there a better way to write this query? Can I use Calender or Tally table?

```
with days_num as  
(
  select
    *,
    case 
      when start_day = 'monday' then 1
      when start_day = 'tuesday' then 2
      when start_day = 'wednesday' then 3
      when start_day = 'thursday' then 4
      when start_day = 'friday' then 5
    end as start_day_num,

    case 
      when end_day = 'monday' then 1
      when end_day = 'tuesday' then 2
      when end_day = 'wednesday' then 3
      when end_day = 'thursday' then 4
      when end_day = 'friday' then 5
    end as end_day_num

  from times
),
day_diff as
(
  select
    emp_id,
    case
      when  
        (end_day_num - start_day_num) = 0
      then
        1
      else
        (end_day_num - start_day_num)
    end as total_diff
  from days_num  
)

select emp_id,
  sum(total_diff) as uniq_working_days
from day_diff
group by
  emp_id
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: for values `(1, 1, 'monday', 'wednesday'),(1, 2, 'monday', 'tuesday'),(1, 3, 'monday', 'tuesday');` empid_1 has worked 3 distinct days (monday, tuesday, wednesday), the fiddle/query returns 4

Comment: @lptr it is  ```(1, 1, 'monday', 'wednesday'),(1, 2, 'monday', 'tuesday'),(1, 3, 'friday', 'friday');```

Comment: Your query doesn't actually work. If you change `1 2 'monday' 'tuesday'` to `1 2 'monday' 'wednesday'` the result should still be 4 days but it returns 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to basically find the intersection of the days worked by each `emp_id` on each `task` with all the days of the week, and then count the distinct days:

```
with days_num as (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    VALUES ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 2), ('wednesday', 3), ('thursday', 4), ('friday', 5)
  ) AS d (day, day_no)
),
emp_day_nums as (
  select emp_id, d1.day_no AS start_day_no, d2.day_no AS end_day_no
  from times t
  join days_num d1 on d1.day = t.start_day
  join days_num d2 on d2.day = t.end_day
)
select emp_id, count(distinct d.day_no) AS distinct_days
from emp_day_nums e
join days_num d on d.day_no between e.start_day_no and e.end_day_no
group by emp_id
```

Output:

```
emp_id  distinct_days
1       4
2       5
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c721/10)

Comment: I didn't see your answer when writing mine. Now I see I was making things more complicated than necessary. I like your solution.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yeah - I initially started down the recursive CTE path myself but realised using a `join` with `between` as the condition achieves the same result more readily...

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach to simplify the statement in the question(fiddle), is to use `VALUES` table value constructor and appropriate joins:

```
SELECT 
   t.emp_id,
   SUM(CASE 
      WHEN d1.day_no = d2.day_no THEN 1
      ELSE d2.day_no - d1.day_no
   END) AS no_of_days
FROM times t
JOIN (VALUES ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 2), ('wednesday', 3), ('thursday', 4), ('friday', 5)) d1 (day, day_no) 
   ON t.start_day = d1.day
JOIN (VALUES ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 2), ('wednesday', 3), ('thursday', 4), ('friday', 5)) d2 (day, day_no) 
   ON t.end_day = d2.day
GROUP BY t.emp_id
```

But if you want to count the **distinct** days, the statement is different. You need to find all days between the `start_day` and `end_day` range and count the distinct days:

```
;WITH daysCTE (day, day_no) AS (
   SELECT 'monday', 1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'tuesday', 2 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'wednesday', 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'thursday', 4 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'friday', 5 
)
SELECT t.emp_id, COUNT(DISTINCT d3.day_no)
FROM times t
JOIN daysCTE d1 ON t.start_day = d1.day
JOIN daysCTE d2 ON t.end_day = d2.day
JOIN daysCTE d3 ON d3.day_no BETWEEN d1.day_no AND d2.day_no
GROUP BY t.emp_id
```

Comment: This query (as with OPs original query) does not work, if you change `1        2     'monday'  'tuesday'  ` to `1        2     'monday'  'wednesday'  ` the result should still be 4 days but it returns 5.

Comment: @Nick, sorry, I can't understand. Based on OPs explanations, there are 2 days between `monday` and `wednesday`. Am I missing something?

Comment: change the input data as I described, and your query returns 5. However the answer should still be 4 as there are still only 4 unique days worked.

Comment: @Nick, now I understand your point. But if I change the values in the OPs fiddle, the result will be `5`, not `4`. This answer just suggests more simplier statement. Thanks.

Comment: OPs query is wrong too. The **correct** answer with that data is 4, as there are only 4 unique days.

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as 
(Select id, start_day as day
   group by id, start_day
 union 
 Select id, end_day as day
   group by id, end_day
)

select id, count(day)
from cte
group by id
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25717090)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not correct. Try Monday to Tuesday with Wednesday to Thursday. This should result in 4 days, but your query returns 2 days. Your query doesn't even detect whether two ranges are adjacent or overlapping or neither.

One way to solve this is to write a recursive CTE to get all days from a range and then count distinct days.

```
with weekdays (day_name, day_number) as
(
  select * from (values ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 2), ('wednesday', 3),
                        ('thursday', 4), ('friday', 5)) as t(x,y)
)
, emp_days(emp_id, day, last_day)
as
(
  select emp_id, wds.day_number, wde.day_number
  from times t
  join weekdays wds on wds.day_name = t.start_day
  join weekdays wde on wde.day_name = t.end_day
  union all
  select emp_id, day + 1, last_day
  from emp_days
  where day < last_day
)
select emp_id, count(distinct day)
from emp_days
group by emp_id
order by emp_id;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4a5ac/16

<sub>(As can be seen I could not apply the values constructor directly as in `with weekdays (day_name, day_number) as (values ('monday', 1), ...)`. I don't know why. Is that SQL Server or me? Well, with the additional select it works :-)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @times table
(
  emp_id int,
  task_id int,
  start_day varchar(50),
  end_day varchar(50)
);

insert into @times(emp_id, task_id, start_day, end_day)
values
(1, 1, 'monday', 'wednesday'),
(1, 2, 'monday', 'tuesday'),
(1, 3, 'friday', 'friday'),
--
(2, 1, 'monday', 'friday'),
(2, 2, 'tuesday', 'wednesday'),
--
(3, 1, 'monday', 'wednesday'),
(3, 2, 'monday', 'tuesday'),
(3, 3, 'monday', 'tuesday');

--for sql 2019, APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT() eliminates distinct sort (!!)...
-- ...with a clustered index on emp_id (to eliminate the hashed aggregation) the query cost gets 5 times cheaper ("overlooking" the increase in memory) !!??!!
/*
select t.emp_id, APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(v.val) as distinctweekdays
from
(
select *, .........
*/


select t.emp_id, count(distinct v.val) as distinctweekdays
from
(
select *, 
case start_day when 'monday' then 1
      when 'tuesday' then 2
      when 'wednesday' then 3
      when 'thursday' then 4
      when 'friday' then 5
    end as start_day_num,
case end_day when 'monday' then 1
      when 'tuesday' then 2
      when 'wednesday' then 3
      when 'thursday' then 4
      when 'friday' then 5
    end as end_day_num
from @times
) as t
join (values(1),(2), (3), (4), (5)) v(val) on v.val between t.start_day_num and t.end_day_num
group by t.emp_id;
```

Comment: Request you to write a description of your code how it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tmp 
     AS (SELECT emp_id, 
                task_id, 
                start_day, 
                end_day, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN start_day = 'monday' THEN 1 
                  WHEN start_day = 'tuesday' THEN 2 
                  WHEN start_day = 'wednesday' THEN 3 
                  WHEN start_day = 'thursday' THEN 4 
                  WHEN start_day = 'friday' THEN 5 
                  WHEN start_day = 'saturday' THEN 6 
                  WHEN start_day = 'sunday' THEN 7 
                END AS start_d, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN end_day = 'monday' THEN 1 
                  WHEN end_day = 'tuesday' THEN 2 
                  WHEN end_day = 'wednesday' THEN 3 
                  WHEN end_day = 'thursday' THEN 4 
                  WHEN end_day = 'friday' THEN 5 
                  WHEN end_day = 'saturday' THEN 6 
                  WHEN end_day = 'sunday' THEN 7 
                END AS end_d 
         FROM   #tmp) 
SELECT emp_id, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN end_d >= start_d THEN end_d - start_d + 1 
             WHEN end_d < start_d THEN end_d + 7 - start_d + 1 
           END) AS day_diff 
FROM   tmp 
GROUP  BY emp_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT emp_id, (MAX(Monday) + MAX(Tuesday)+ MAX(Wednesday)+ MAX(Thursday) + MAX(Friday)) Total
    FROM
        (SELECT *, IIF(1>=start_num AND 1<=end_num, 1, 0) Monday, IIF(2>=start_num AND 2<=end_num, 1, 0) Tuesday, 
                  IIF(3>=start_num AND 3<=end_num, 1, 0) Wednesday, IIF(4>=start_num AND 4<=end_num, 1, 0) Thursday, 
IIF(5>=start_num AND 5<=end_num, 1, 0) Friday
        FROM
            (SELECT emp_id, CASE WHEN start_day = 'Monday' THEN 1
                           WHEN start_day = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
                           WHEN start_day = 'Wednesday' THEN 3
                           WHEN start_day = 'Thursday' THEN 4
                           ELSE 5
                      END AS start_num,
                      CASE WHEN end_day = 'Monday' THEN 1
                           WHEN end_day = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
                           WHEN end_day = 'Wednesday' THEN 3
                           WHEN end_day = 'Thursday' THEN 4
                           ELSE 5
                      END AS end_num
            FROM Times) a
        )b
    GROUP BY emp_id
```